# intellij generate JDocs html files

Tags: intellij-idea, jsdoc

I'm writing an website with intelliJ and my JS files have JSDocs annotations as supported by IntlliJ.
I there a way to produce  JSDocs html files like with javadocs?

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-jsdoc-comments.html

Comment: @NimChimpsky i know how to create the comments.
I want to generate the documents i html like with JavaDoc

Comment: if you read the link, or looked at other questions here you would find your solution. You have to dl jsdoc yourself and generate them "manually"